# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery when deployed

Tags: iis, .net-core, iis-10, antiforgerytoken

**Background**: I deployed a small .NET core web app to Windows 2019 server on IIS10. (On AWS EC2 t2.micro)

**1.** My web app has been working successfully for about a month. I have
deployed changes to the server often and with no problem until
today.

**2.** Works on my localhost

When I uploaded changes, now I get an error when logging in. I have hardcoded the user/pass on the controller so I cant see why I SUDDENLY started getting this error.

```
ActionName: UploadFile.Controllers.LoginController.Index (UploadFile)

An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.

Exception: 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
 ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {6e631e8e-a970-4ab7-bddc-4b68c37f9aac} was not found in the key ring.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
```

........

The controller code looks like

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(string inputEmail, string inputPassword)
{
    if (inputEmail == "email@em.com" && inputPassword =="pass"){
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "" });
    }

    ViewBag.Error = true;
    return View();
}
```

and the view has :

```
<form class="form-signin" asp-action="Index"  style="padding-top: 25px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I increased the memory of the server. I was using an AWS virtual machine of type t2.micro which has 1 GB of memory.